# Is there such an isotopy for every homology sphere?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $n \geq 3$, and $\Sigma^{n-1} \subset \mathbf{S}^n$ be a *smoothly and properly embedded*, orientable, and connected submanifold of the sphere. This divides the sphere into two open sets, $U_-$ and $U_+$. My question is about isotopies in $B^{n+1} \subset \mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ from $U_-$ to $U_+$, leaving $\Sigma$ pointwise fixed.

Such an isotopy can only exist if $\Sigma$ is a homology sphere, by the Mayer–Vietoris sequence. Consider the following three statements, each stronger than the next.

(i) There is an isotopy in $B^{n+1}$ from $U_-$ to $U_+$ leaving $\Sigma$ fixed.

(ii) There is a diffeomorphism in $\mathbf{S}^n$ from $U_-$ to $U_+$ leaving $\Sigma$ fixed.

(iii) The surface $\Sigma$ is a homology sphere.

**Question.** Are the converses true, that is: does (iii) imply (ii) and (ii) imply (i)?

*Comment.* I suspect the answer is a resounding *no*, but I don't know algebraic topology well enough to understand how wild homology spheres can get when one restricts to those that are properly embedded. I've modified the question from a previous version, that was a bit less precise.

Comment: Although this question asks explicitly about the smooth setting. In the topological category (iii) does not imply (ii). The Alexander horned sphere is an embedding of $S^2$ into $S^3$ such that one of the the two components is a standard ball, whereas the other one is not.

Comment: If we look at the question whether (iii) implies (ii). In the special case of $\Sigma=S^n$ there is the Schoenflies problem/theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem). Especially in the section about generalizations, it says that in the smooth category this it is still open whether $U_+$ is a ball in dimension four. I would be surprised if there is a statement saying that $U_+$ and $U_-$ are diffeomorphic.

Comment: My algebraic topology is a bit rusty, but I'm pretty sure (ii) (and probably also (i)) imply that the U_\pm are simply connected and hence contractible.  While (iii) only implies they are homology balls (at least when n\geq 4 where you can get homology spheres that aren't homotopy spheres).